# Try does not catch exception in DllImport function

Tags: c#, c++

I call C++ function from C# project:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("C.dll")]
public static extern int FillSlist(out string slist);
```

and then

```
try
{
  FillSlist(out slist);
}
catch
{
}
```

C++ dll is protected by third-party tool, so some code is being performed before FillSlist is really executed. Something really bad happens while this third-party code is executed and the program stops working at all. Neither "try" isolates the problem nor "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException" is executed.

Is there anything that can help to isolate crash of C++ function from C# calling code?

Comment: I've got the same problem on .NET Compact Framework 3.5 under Windows CE. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this running on CLR 4.0?  If so ...

If an exception does not get caught in an open catch block as demonstrated in your code it's because the CLR considers it a corrupted state exception and is by default not handled by user code.  Instead it propagates up and causes the process to terminate.

It does this for a reason for these types of exceptions there is no action managed code can take to correct the problem.  The only possible solution is to terminate the process.

You can override this behavior by adding an `HandledCorruptedStateException` attribute to the method.  But generally speaking this is a bad idea.

More details

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

If not then it's possible the program is simply crashing out in native code and execution never properly returns to managed code.

Comment: Any ideas why does it happen in CLR 3.5?

Comment: I just hit this error myself: .NET 3.5 calling C++ dll; exception thrown from DLL causes my C# app to crash unceremoniously.  Maybe I'm missing something here, but the link you provided seems only to give a solution for .NET 4.0.  Is there some way I can protect against exceptions in the C++ DLL in 3.5?

Comment: @mack369 - the question is more how to solve it in 3.5  I've also just hit this problem.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Shaul - No, I haven't found any real solution. I've just worked around the bug inside the native library

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to handle these exceptions?  In my case I have multiple modules that might be able to keep operating even if one module is corrupted and should be shut down.