# How Do Exceptions Work When Using DLLImport

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I am using DLLImport to call the GhostScript library from a C# application.

So I have some code like this,

```
[DllImport("gsdll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_init_with_args")]
private static extern int gsapi_init_with_args(IntPtr instance, int argc, IntPtr argv);

try 
{ 
    intReturn = gsapi_init_with_args(intGSInstanceHandle, intElementCount, intptrArgs); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message, ex);
}
```

I am going to look at the GhostScript source code, which is written in C or C++, but in general I was wondering what would happen if the GhostScript code threw an unhandled exception? Would that be caught by the catch there, or would it have to look like this,

```
catch
{
    // blah
}
```

Comment: possible dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344087/try-does-not-catch-exception-in-dllimport-function

Comment: This is .NET 4.0 yes. I am wondering though, perhaps this question is somewhat meaningless in this case. I see that GhostScript is written in C, so it should never throw any exceptions right? Anyway it would be good to know what catch does with C++ exceptions.

Comment: The OS can throw an exception even if the dll can not.

Comment: I am using a different dll, and getting issues with exceptions being raised on past catch (Exception e), despite Microsoft saying that should work.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404228(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't throw an exception, you're meant to look at the return codes.
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/7.04/API.htm#return_codes

Pretty standard method for C programming, return code of non zero for an error, sometimes followed by a 2nd API call to retrieve more details of the error.